# Dagger2: Is it possible to inject based on Android Version?

Tags: android, dagger-2

Is it possible I can use Dagger2 to inject a concrete implementation based on SDK version?

For example

```
// MediaPlayerComponent.class
@Component(modules = {MediaPlayerModule.class}
public interface MediaPlayerComponent
{
    void inject(MediaPlayerUI ui)
}

// MediaPlayerUI.java
public class MediaPlayerUI
{
    @Inject
    public MediaPlayer mPlayer;
}

// GingerbreadMediaPlayer.java
public class GingerbreadMediaPlayer extends MediaPlayer {...}

// IceCreamSandwichMediaPlayer.java
public class IceCreamSandwichMediaPlayer extends MediaPlayer {...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just decide which of both implementations should be returned in the `MediaPlayerModule` module in the concrete method annotated with `@Provides`, the one that returns a generic `MediaPlayer`.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically that's possible, I haven't done it before since I didn't have the need to but I think the following scenario would work:

- You should have one parent ApplicationComponent that defines the needs of your app. Let's call it ApplicationComponent.
- Now let's assume you want to have 2 different dependencies for API21 and above and for API below 21. You should create two components that inherits from your application component let's call them Application21Component and ApplicationBelow21Component.
- For each of the two components you should have a different ApplicationModule that tells you application component how to get the dependencies needed
- In your application class the body of "getComponent" function will be something similar to the following

  `public ApplicationComponent getComponent(){
      if (mApplicationComponent == null) {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
              mApplicationComponent = DaggerApplication21Component.builder()
                      .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                      .build();
          } else {
              mApplicationComponent = DaggerApplicationBelow21Component.builder()
                      .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                      .build();
          }
      }
      return mApplicationComponent;
  }`